# Reference variables from a base DockerFile in child dockerfiles?

Tags: docker

I am currently working on splitting a huge DockerFile into separate DockerFiles but some variables that are defined in the huge DockerFile needs to be used in the separate DockerFiles. Does Docker have a concept of importing common variables across a set of DockerFiles or some other inheritance mechanism?

I would like to avoid having to maintain duplicate variables across multiple dockerfiles.

As an example:

```
ARG basic_user="user"
USER ${basic_user}
```

Comment: What kind of variables are we talking about here — `ARG`, `ENV`, shell variables, what?

Comment: Updated post with simple example

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is the **ONBUILD** command. [Docker ONBUILD command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild). This command will allow a child container to inherit commands that are declared in your parent Dockerfile and be used by any child Dockerfiles that use the parent as a base image.

Here's an example:

*Parent Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ONBUILD ARG ARG_1=arg1
ONBUILD ENV CHILD_VAR=${ARG_1}
ONBUILD ENTRYPOINT ["printenv"]
```

For the sake of this example, I build this Dockerfile as `docker build -t parent .`

*Child Dockerfile*

```
FROM parent:latest
```

Build this Dockerfile as `docker build -t child .` This child container will now have an environment variable with a value specified by ARG_1 from the parent. Test this with the following and you'll get the result `arg1`:

```
docker run --name=child child CHILD_VAR
```

It's important to note that in this example, by using ONBUILD the parent will not have an environment variable called CHILD_VAR nor will it have the specified entrypoint. Only Dockerfiles that use the parent as a base image will.

Comment: but can I reference the parent var ARG_1 in the child dockerfile with the value it has in the parent dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. In this case, you would just have `ONBUILD ARG ARG_1=arg1` in the parent, and then in the child you can reference it via expansion - for example `ENV CHILD_VAR=$ARG_1`

Answer (score 1):

The `ENV` values in Dockerfiles are persisted and they are inherited by descendant Dockerfiles. [Dockerfile ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)

On the other hand, `ARG` values are not persisted and thus are *not* inhereted descendant Dockerfiles. [Dockerfile ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables)